# Magento 2.3 + store pickup : main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, critical

I am locked, i have the following error :

> main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for
>   'frontend/WEB/website/en_US/Magestore_Storepickup/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css.map'
>   [] [] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for
>   'frontend/WEB/website/en_US/Magestore_Storepickup/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css.map'
>   []

I don't understand this error because bootstrap.css.map is nowhere called in the source code according to VScode search.
Does someone had the same problem ? how did you solved it ?

Comment: When this error has occurred on your website?

Comment: At the moment to place order, actually is not display on the website, the website just don't do action when I place order so I checked the network console and find an 500  status so I check in bin/log and this error is in system.log